# Online personal finance with QIF import

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for an online personal finance management solution.

A crucial requirement is that it supports import of transactions and accounts from QIF or alike, since I have a few year's worth of transactions and accounts in a QIF file and want to keep it all.

My findings so far:

1. The all-too-much-hyped `mint.com` doesn't do that and it's not clear whether it's going to be implemented at all.
2. `Moneystrands.com` has only support for import per account, but not import for the whole QIF containing all the accounts and transactions.
3. `xero.com` seems to have import of QIF per account (i.e. you'd have to split your single QIF file with all the accounts somehow) yet it failed with an error message about date format when I tried to import a file.

Comment: In case anyone wonders where did it all go, I actually decided to ditch online and settled on the offline version of YNAB, which does one thing really well - budgeting.

Now I am actually somewhat hesitant to use any online services, other than banks, for management of my transactions.

Answer (score 0):

The QIF format is easily parse-able, and you can convert it to CSV or OFX or any other foramt. I don't think the format limits your choices.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain... as well as the websites you've tried, I've also played with [Buxfer](https://www.buxfer.com/) (free) but couldn't get the alleged QIF or CSV import functionality to work - maybe you'll have more luck.

Some sites that make you pay for this feature include [ClearCheckbook](https://www.clearcheckbook.com/), [Cashoo](https://kashoo.com/) and [Mvelopes](https://www.mvelopes.com/); I'm sure there are plenty more.

Personally, I don't feel this justifies a paid service.  Given the volatility of this rapidly growing software segment (and my personal concerns over security and lack of UK support) I'm going to settle for an Excel workbook and [Qif To Excel](http://www.databiz.uk.com/QifToExcel.asp) converter for now - or maybe [write my own parser in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20151002062703/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucabol/archive/2007/08/31/parsing-qif-quicken-files-in-c.aspx).

Fingers crossed that Google release a financial app soon, and the rest will have to up their game...